# Whats the point of the rule that enforces the constructor summary to say "Initializes a new instance of the <whatever> class"?

Tags: stylecop

I really do want to understand what is the point of this rule. Isn't it obvious that a constructor "Initializes a new instance of the  class"?

Feels like it is the same of forcing the summary of methods to say "this is a method, it will do something, return and maybe return a value"

Answer (score 2):

IMO, this one is mostly about consistency of constructor summaries, not the wording of any particular constructor summary.  If you require that constructors have summaries but do not check for consistent wording, you'll end up with a variety of styles of descriptions.  This isn't exactly the end of the world, but it is the sort of thing that can annoy API users.

If you have reason to keep the rule enables and want an easy way to generate standard constructor summaries, you might want to take a look at [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx).